# Convert SQL to Linq statement in MVC view

Tags: sql, linq, model-view-controller

I am trying to get a distinct list from my table in my MVC View, but it has a Primary key that is unique and has 1000's of rows in the table. Essentially this is a staging table that has mass data, and by referencing the RunID I can move/update data as I need.

In SQL terms this is what I need

```
Select a.*,Min([ID]) as 'ID'

From
(
SELECT [Group]
      ,[Entity]
      ,[Enterprise]
      ,[RunID]
  FROM [CashManager].[Upload]

  Group By [RunID],[Group]
      ,[Entity]
      ,[Enterprise]) a

      Left join [CashManager].Upload On a.RunID=[CashManager].Upload.RunID

      GRoup by a.RunID, a.[Group], a.[Entity], a.[Enterprise]
```

in my View I have the following

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(u => new {u.RunId, u.Group, u.Entity, u.Enterprise, u.FileName, u.Timestamp, u.Id }))
```

Now when I omit the ID column (which is the primary key) I get the answer (in terms of rows) I need, but when editing etc I need the ID value, so it doesnt work.

So if you could help me get either my view statement right, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go down a different route in the end, and solved my problem using Azure Data Factory functionality (I am already using it as a part of my project)

I used a Query to populate my dataset

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your SQL query

```sql
Select 
   S.[Group],
   S.[Entity],
   S.[Enterprise],
   S.[RunID],
   S.[ID]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
     a.[Group],
     a.[Entity],
     a.[Enterprise],
     a.[RunID],
     a.[ID],
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTTION BY a.[RunID], a.[Group], a.[Entity], a.[Enterprise] ORDER BY a.[ID]
     ) AS RN
  FROM [CashManager].[Upload] a
) S
WHERE S.RN = 1
```

Answering future questions: It is not possible via pure EF Core LINQ, because it does not support Window Functions.